# c# unable to edit datarow in dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, datarow

I'm trying to edit the data in a dataset (change the value in a column on one row), which is not linked to a database.  I've been googling for about an hour with no results and no good examples out there.   Hopefully someone can help me.

My table (DataTable1) has these columns - ThreadID (string, PK), StatusText (string).

I can select a row in a DataGridView, and get the ThreadID value.  No matter how I've tried to edit the row in the associated dataset, either nothing happens or I get an error.  Here's what I have now:

```
string sThreadID = "";
sThreadID = gridThreads.Rows[gridThreads.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();  // gives me a good id, which is in the dataset
DataRow drRow = dataThreads.Tables["DataTable1"].Rows.Find(sThreadID);
drRow["StatusText"] = "Test";
```

The error I get when getting the row (3rd line) is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".  I can't create a new DataRow object because there's no public constructor for it (according to my research).

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I'm not familiar with working with datasets. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check `drRow != null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does drRow know what "statusText" is?  You may be only getting a shalllow copy, try cloning/copy so that the data types of the row get copied as well.  Just an idea.

Comment: Also, try indexing with 0 instead of DataTable1, unless that is truely the name of the table.

Comment: You know what, it was indeed named "DataTable1", but when I switched to the index it worked.  Thanks Induster

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen that `dataThreads` or `Tables["DataTable1"]` is `null` ?

To create a new row, use the `NewRow()` method of the data table.